# Is any convention to tell the propeller rotation direction of an airplane?

Tags: aircraft-design, propeller, single-engine

[image: Single Engine Airplane]

[image: De Haviland DHC-5 Buffallo]

[image: Turn-Left Tendencies]

Here are two airplane with single and dual engine.

From single engine airplane we know there is TURN LEFT tendencies. There are four tendencies (Torque reaction, Precession, Slip Stream, and P-Factor) caused by the propeller rotation, which it rotate clockwise seen from the tail to the nose side. If the rotation is opposite, probably the name will be TURN RIGHT tendencies.

Then my question, is any convention to tell the propeller rotation, such as, rotation is must be seen from tail or pilot side. I.e:

- Clockwise, mean the propeller is rotates clockwise seen from the tail nose side. Vice versa:
- Anti/contra/counter clockwise, mean the propeller is rotate anti clock wise seen from nose to the tail side.

The four tendencies are like confirming that the rotation is clockwise seen from tail side to the nose side. But however, I need a valid info regarding this, which expected the convention is applicable to another airplane with multiple engines/propellers and it will confirm that no need to tell where our stand point when saying the propeller direction. It is enough to say, clockwise or anti/counter/contra clock wise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say "clockwise" or "counter-clockwise" it is generally accepted that this would be the view as if you were standing *behind* the aircraft. Unless it is otherwise stated, this is the convention that you can assume.

If you need a way to tell by looking at the prop, the thicker part is the leading edge. In the first photo you posted, this would rotate counter-clockwise from the perspective of the photographer, or clockwise from the perspective of behind the aircraft. This is, by convention, a clockwise rotating propeller.

Comment: ***When you say "clockwise" or "counter-clockwise" it is generally accepted that this would be the view as if you were standing behind the aircraft. Unless it is otherwise stated, this is the convention that you can assume.*** Thank you for this confirmation.

Comment: That's why I ask this question as perfective of photographer is different than convention. To know the convention will make easier to tell every one without to complicated explanation.